# XmlParseException when using binding in DataTemplate to access ressource with a non-string key

Tags: wpf, xaml, binding, resourcedictionary, staticresource

I have a DataTemplate in a style for ListViews.
ScriptAdvised is an enumeration.
The error comes from the StackPanel background attribute because if I remove it then it works.
My objective here is to access one of the brushes according to the Advised property (which is also of the ScriptAdvised type).

When I run my program, this exception is thrown :

> System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException : 'A 'Binding' cannot be set on the 'DeferrableContent' property of type 'ResourceDictionary'. A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.'

```xml
<DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static logic:ScriptAdvised.Yes}" Color="Green" Opacity="0.15"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static logic:ScriptAdvised.Limited}" Color="Yellow" Opacity="0.15"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static logic:ScriptAdvised.No}" Color="Red" Opacity="0.15"/>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <StackPanel Background="{StaticResource {Binding Advised}}" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <CheckBox/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I don't understand because I don't have any explicit ResourceDictionaries in my application.

Comment: No because Advised is a property of the object I want to reference using the DataTemplate. I still don't understand. Why is it invalid?

Comment: You are apparently trying to bind the ResourceKey property of a StaticResourceExtension, which is not possible because StaticResourceExtension is not a DependencyObject and its ResourceKey property is not a dependency property.

Comment: Okay then, how am i supposed to get the correct brush based on the value of Advised?

Comment: By a StackPanel Style with DataTriggers on the Advised property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `Style` with `DataTriggers` to set the `Background` based on the value of `Advised`. Something like this:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Yes" Color="Green" Opacity="0.15"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Limited" Color="Yellow" Opacity="0.15"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="No" Color="Red" Opacity="0.15"/>
    </DataTemplate.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <StackPanel.Style>
            <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Advised}" Value="{x:Static logic:ScriptAdvised.Yes}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Yes}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Advised}" Value="{x:Static logic:ScriptAdvised.Limited}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Limited}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Advised}" Value="{x:Static logic:ScriptAdvised.No}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource No}" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </StackPanel.Style>
        <CheckBox/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```